# Webpack - WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB)

Tags: javascript, webpack

When I run webpack in production mode.
There is a warning that asset size limit (exceed).
How can I run without this error?

In my project, I include css, and I see some node_module directory include in the webpack build.
But if I exclude node_module of css it will have the error.

The following is the output when I try to build my project with webpack.

```
[mai@localhost dssoft]$ yarn run build
yarn run v1.9.2
$ webpack --config webpack.config.js
Hash: a5edfb917e6152759218
Version: webpack 4.16.3
Time: 16592ms
Built at: 08/07/2018 7:58:40 PM
                                 Asset      Size  Chunks                    Chunk Names
  f4769f9bdb7466be65088239c12046d1.eot  19.7 KiB          [emitted]         
448c34a56d699c29117adc64c43affeb.woff2  17.6 KiB          [emitted]         
 fa2772327f55d8198301fdb8bcfc8158.woff  22.9 KiB          [emitted]         
  e18bbf611f2a2e43afc071aa2f4e1512.ttf  44.3 KiB          [emitted]         
  89889688147bd7575d6327160d64e760.svg   106 KiB          [emitted]         
                             bundle.js   624 KiB       0  [emitted]  [big]  main
Entrypoint main [big] = bundle.js
 [22] ./node_modules/react-router-dom/es/index.js + 34 modules 80.3 KiB {0} [built]
      |    35 modules
 [29] ./node_modules/react-bootstrap/es/index.js + 104 modules 301 KiB {0} [built]
      |    105 modules
 [90] ./js/reducers/index.js 650 bytes {0} [built]
[116] ./node_modules/react-redux/es/index.js + 23 modules 43 KiB {0} [built]
      |    24 modules
[121] multi whatwg-fetch ./js/App.js 40 bytes {0} [built]
[122] ./js/App.js 5.17 KiB {0} [built]
[134] ./js/actions/index.js 2.31 KiB {0} [built]
[213] ./js/configureStore.js 1.4 KiB {0} [built]
[221] ./js/pages/Index.js 479 bytes {0} [built]
[222] ./js/pages/Signup.js 8.04 KiB {0} [built]
[227] ./js/pages/Login.js 7.67 KiB {0} [built]
[228] ./js/pages/Logout.js 620 bytes {0} [built]
[229] ./js/pages/NotFound.js 2.86 KiB {0} [built]
[230] ./js/pages/Events.js 3.51 KiB {0} [built]
[244] ./js/App.css 1.04 KiB {0} [built]
    + 231 hidden modules

WARNING in asset size limit: The following asset(s) exceed the recommended size limit (244 KiB).
This can impact web performance.
Assets: 
  bundle.js (624 KiB)

WARNING in entrypoint size limit: The following entrypoint(s) combined asset size exceeds the recommended limit (244 KiB). This can impact web performance.
Entrypoints:
  main (624 KiB)
      bundle.js


WARNING in webpack performance recommendations: 
You can limit the size of your bundles by using import() or require.ensure to lazy load some parts of your application.
For more info visit https://webpack.js.org/guides/code-splitting/
Done in 20.99s.
```

Additional webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'production',
  entry: [
    'whatwg-fetch',
    path.resolve(__dirname, 'src', 'App.js')
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /\/node_modules\//,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [ 
            'style-loader',
            'css-loader'
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpg|gif|svg|eot|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
        loader: 'url-loader',
        options: {
          limit: 10000
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public'),
  },
};
```

Comment: What happened when you tried splitting up your app with import() or require.ensure, as the message told you to?

Comment: You're importing the entire reactstrap JS bundle, but i doubt your using them all. You can use treeshaking and direct references to the components you use to trim file size. React should also probably be removed, and added into your HTML template from a CDN. Then finally you can gzip and minify.

Comment: Hi @damanptyltd, thank you very much for your suggestion.

Comment: No worries. I'd also recommend splitting out CSS and assets to their own files, and minify CSS appropriately.

Comment: "How can I run without this error?" - Warnings are not errors. What you are doing should work fine, it's just that WebPack _recommends_ keeping resources under 244KiB but it's not necessary

Comment: Also excluding `devtool` from production config can reduce size.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can hide these warnings/hints by setting `performance.hints = false`:

```
{
  performance: {
    hints: false
  }
}
```

See [the docs for more information](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/performance/#performance-hints).

Of course, the hint is there for a reason and you should look into ways of reducing your bundle size. For example by using code splitting.

Answer (score 38):

Webpacks warning size seems out of date.  Instead of just ignoring it you can set it to a more meaningful size limit inside the module.exports object.

```js
    module.exports = {
       ....
       performance: {
            maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
            maxAssetSize: 512000
       },
       ....
    }
```

Comment: Where can I set these limits?

Comment: @devsat Add it to you module.exports json in your webpack.confic.js